# how to create a static filled form in pdf document from a php page having form elements

Tags: php, html, email, pdf

I am doing a website using php , i need create a pdf doc from html page and attach that pdf doc in email. i have tried `dompdf` , but it didn't works , it won't shows the checkboxes and images, I am attaching my html page[image]

The form contains a lot of checkboxes, selectionbox ,textarea, images.  Is their any way to create the pdf doc ? I don't want to change the form just need to convert it to pdf. Please help.

### Dompdf

```
$html=$this->load->view('controller/viewfile', $data, true);
   $this->load->helper(array('dompdf','file'));
     pdf_create($html, 'designdaytona.com');
    $data = pdf_create($html, '', false);
   write_file('name', $data);
```

### dompdf helper

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE) 
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();

    if ($stream) {
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
    } else {
        return $dompdf->output();
    }

    /*$var=$dompdf->get_canvas();
   $var->new_page('bonjour', '2');*/

  }
```

Comment: Can you post what you have attempted using `dompdf`?

Comment: @Nicarus i have added the dompdf code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) library i found it very useful.
You can create form inside pdf take a look at http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_014.pdf

Comment: i want to create the pdf doc without any javascript functions, need to show the checkboxes checked ,no need to remove the selection

Comment: yah but in this library i don't think they user JS

Comment: just look at it..its build on PHP oop and they provide extreme example for how to do that.